# Getting child content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the folowing to get child title and content. Each child has a gallery and a short code in the content editor in the content, but I only get the gallery and not shortcode. It isn't something to do with the short code but rather on the content as I tried to add some paragraph to the content after the gallery and it does not show up.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$page->ID.'&sort_order=asc&number=3&sort_column=menu_order&parent='.$page->ID);
foreach($pages as $page) {
    $content = $page->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
?>

    <div class="span4">
       <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </div>
```

I think `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);` is basically stripping out part of the content. Any idea why it is not showing the shortcode?

Comment: Is the shortcode still in the content when you print it? Or does the shortcode disappear and is not replaced by the content it should be replaced by? (I want to be sure I understand your question perfectly.)

Comment: Literally, I have this in the content I have:

[gallery ids="181,22,28"]
[next_page][previous_page]

And in the html when the page is loaded, I only have the gallery, nothing else

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name: home
  */
  get_header(); ?>

 <?php $counter = 1 ?>
 <div class="row-fluid"> 
 <?php
$args = array(
 'child_of' => 4,
 'parent' => 0,
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
 $childrens =   query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent=4&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');

  foreach ( $childrens as $children ) :
 query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent='.$children->ID.'&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');
if ( have_posts ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  <? if ($counter % 3 == 0): ?>
 <div id="content" class="row-fluid"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
   <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php
endwhile;
 endif;
endforeach;
?>
 </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```